# Should I use the same server for webserver and the database?

Tags: configuration, onion-services, web-hosting

I want to start hosting my hidden service and be as secure as possible.

It is currently just some PHP Code and a MySQL database.
Now I am wondering if I need a external server to host my database or if I should host the database on the same server the webserver is running.

So if my webserver gets compromised the hackers do not have access to my database and if would that protect me at all, since i have to store the credentials from the database somewhere.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think this is really specific to onion services, and you'd probably get better help on a web hosting forum.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to split your system in order to improve the security. Anyway your database credentials will be stored somewhere in php files to provide access to your scripts. You'd rater secure your system, e.g. use RSA key to login without password